# zoom in effect doesn't smooth jquery

Tags: jquery

I trying to convert a [css slider](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3FullscreenSlideshow/index3.html) to jquery slider. the zoom in animation is so smooth in css version but it doesnt in my jquery version.

I use `.animate()` function:

```
dv_image_2
    .animate({opacity: 1}, 1000)
    .animate({
        width:'+=70px',
        height:'+=70px',
        top: '-=40px',
        left: '-=40px'
    }, 5000, 'linear');
```

to see unsmooth zoom-in: http://jsfiddle.net/9CL4x/1/

I added easing parameter with value linear but nothing changed. what can I do to make animation smooth? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want it to be jQuery? CSS is faster. Easing doesn't have anything to do with smoothness, it's just a speed function for the animation.

Comment: css3 effects alone wont work in most IE browsers

Comment: good point @megaSteve4 espacially IE causes many problem with css that's my main reason to use jquery and I would have more control on the slider with jquery than css.

Comment: Agreed despite being excited about the new functionality of css3 and html 5 - they are still wholly unsupported by a massive percentage of browser users - good ol'jQuery definitely helps fill in the blanks.